# Can I use Physics.CheckSphere with no LayerMask?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using Unity3D and I have a crouch mechanic and to prevent my player from clipping into objects when uncrouching, I use a **CheckSphere** and I place the **ceilingCheck** empty object on the top of my player object (capsule) with a **ceilingDistance** of **0.5f**.

```
isCeilingAbove = Physics.CheckSphere(ceilingCheck.position, ceilingDistance, ceilingMask);
```

The issue is that I don't want to have to manually add invisible objects and then set a "ceiling" layer onto them because it's too much effort when its not needed. I can't use a simple **Raycast** because the sides of my capsule will still clip into objects when uncrouching since the R**aycast** is only a line. I haven't been able to get **SphereCast** to work properly for this and I'm not quite sure what other methods there is.

Is there a way for me to get all masks instead of just one mask like I'm currently doing with "ceilingMask"?

Comment: yes but note a sphere cast on position will check ground as well as height and walls..

Comment: What's the solution in this case? I can't use Physics.AllLayers because I'm not using a Raycast so I'm not sure

Comment: Did you check the documentation? it covers it exactly